# How can I access Google Scholar in w3m through ssh?

Tags: vps, w3m

I have a remote VPS and sometimes I want to browse Google Scholar on it in w3m through ssh.

But Google Scholar says that they can't let you access it for security reasons(with a title "Sorry").
[image]

Can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by add this line to `/etc/hosts`:

```
2404:6800:4008:c06::be scholar.google.com
```